Presto coordinator + Unknown transaction ID exception
from time to time we seen the following exception from presto coordinator logs
WARN    http-worker-937362     io.prestosql.server.ThrowableMapper     Request failed for /v1/statement/executing/89432507_017276200_00296_ha3nh/y8c2534b78ba298be584e55061d7
911bd7b8711dd/1
io.prestosql.NotInTransactionException: Unknown transaction ID: 0a272093-d1f6-4643-9746-89a8c3070b42. Possibly expired? Commands ignored until end of transaction block

from my understanding this issue happens when we try to execute the query which takes more than 5min.
The relevant parameter that can help us with time out of transaction is
transaction.idle-timeout=10min   ( when default is 5min )

but we not sure that increasing the value from 5min to 10min is a good solution and maybe we have other problem that is the root cause of long query that takes too much time
in any case we'll happy to get yours suggestion about transaction.idle-timeout and if in our case if its necessary to increase the default value in order to avoid the exception as already describe up
